# How to initialize a web app?

Tags: initialization, web-applications, embedded-jetty

My Web App will be deployed as a WAR package in a Jetty instance. It needs to perform a lot of caching before serving requests. How do I call the caching method before anything else? is the a static void main() in the web app standard?

Comment: If you want people to answer your questions please accept some answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard (old) way is to code a Servlet which takes care of initialization stuff in its `init()` method. You force it to be initialized at application start by adding a `load-on-startup` positive value in your `web.xml`

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myinit</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.MyInitServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Today it's more usual to have a bean container like Spring, which takes care of this kind of things (instantiating services objects, preloading cacheable sharable data, etc).

Note: this recipe is for webapps in general, not specific to Jetty.

Comment: I like this solution because I can use it with any web app server.
I will need a dummy servlet for that though. Is there a way to perform such initialization without implementing a servlet? Is there a static void main() for web apps?

Comment: It seems adding a ServletContextListener is all that I want.